# Flashbuilder 4, Desktop Air Application - Embed and play Sound

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, audio, flash-builder

I am a complete newbie to Flashbuilder, and I need to learn how to 1.) Embed a sound file (mp3) and 2.) be able to play said file.

I looked it up using Google and all the examples seem to be for AS3, I tried to adapt it as follows but cant get it to play (or should I say I can't hear anything?)

bgmusic is imported at the src level

Test.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.media.Sound;


            [Embed(source="bgmusic.mp3")]
            public var mySound:Class;

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {

                var s:Sound = new mySound() as Sound;
                s.play();

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Button label="Test" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" />
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: Have you tried singleton library from evolve? http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2008/07/15/as3/as3-soundmanager/

Comment: your code should work. It does for me. Are you sure that the embedded source path is right? (though should give an error if not) Stupid question: but do you click the button?